# constructing request data for SOAP endpoint without WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, savon

The endpoint URL looks like this (not an actual url)
https://webservices.abcde.com/ThirdParty/PostData.V55.ashx/ProcessRequest

It does not have a WSDL, and in the documentation, there's a sample request XML.

It's huge. I am adding the first couple lines from it below.

```xml
<MESSAGE xmlns:agentnet="http://services.abcde.com/entity/agentnet/v2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas/v32">
<ABOUT_VERSIONS>
  <ABOUT_VERSION>
    <AboutVersionIdentifier>ClientSystem</AboutVersionIdentifier>
    <DataVersionIdentifier>1.0</DataVersionIdentifier>
    <DataVersionName>ASDFSFD</DataVersionName>
  </ABOUT_VERSION>
</ABOUT_VERSIONS>
<DEAL_SETS>
  <DEAL_SET>
        <DEALS>
          <DEAL>
            <PARTIES/>
            <SERVICES>
              <SERVICE>
                <SERVICE_PRODUCT>
                  <SERVICE_PRODUCT_REQUEST>
                    <EXTENSION>
                      <OTHER>
                        <agentnet:AGENTNET_PRODUCT_REQUEST>
<agentnet:AgentNetServiceType>GET_DATA</agentnet:AgentNetServiceType>
                          <agentnet:AGENTNET_GET_DATA>
                            <agentnet:GetRequestType>ACCOUNTS</agentnet:GetRequestType>
                          </agentnet:AGENTNET_GET_DATA>
                        </agentnet:AGENTNET_PRODUCT_REQUEST>
...
...
...
...
... (the XML is huge)
```

With other endpoints, I was able to use a SOAP library like `savon` to generate the XML payload using a small Ruby Hash(dictionary).

I assume that was possible because those were WSDLs?

Would it be possible to generate the payload the same way by passing only some essential data (for example, `GET_DATA` and `ACCOUNTS` in the example), or should I manually construct the XML payload strings manually (maybe using some XML library)?

I really want to avoid manually constructing XML payloads since the code will not be readable and will be hard to work with in general. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitively create a Savon client without using the WSDL. I personally like this better because I believe it's more performant.

You have to define `endpoint` and `namespace`when you create your client, like this fictitious example:

```
require 'savon'

c = Savon.client(endpoint: "http://www.example.com",
                 namespace: "urn:ns.example.com",
                 log: true,
                 log_level: :debug,
                 pretty_print_xml: true)

r = c.call(:call,
           :message => { 
                  :InquiryParam => [ 
                         {"crmParam" => 123,
                        :attributes! => { "crmParam" => { "name" => "AccountNumber" }}},
                         {"crmParam" => 456,
                        :attributes! => { "crmParam" => { "name" => "history" }}}
                        ]
                  }
          )
```

Comment: I know I can create a Savon client without WSDL. However, when I tried to generate the payload with a small hash, it was merely converting the hash to XML, and it wasn't generating `DEAL_SETS`, `DEALS`, or `PARTIES` in my example. Do I need to manually create those nodes? I'm not a SOAP expert but I thought that information about the fields and the structure of the XML payload came from WSDL.

Comment: yes, you have to create the entire structure as needed as a hash. Savon will convert the hash into correct XML for the payload.

Comment: Is Savon even useful in that case? I think it's useful only if it can know about the structure of the XML through WSDL or something. Also, what is the best way to construct the XML payload in my case? I'm thinking about using a template language like `ERB` to template and generate the XML.

Comment: I always thought about sending verbatim XML as last resort. If you can build your client using standard Ruby objects then Savon will do the work for you. But there a many ways to skin a cat.